# how to fix fixme:thread:NtQueryInformationThread info class 16 not supported yet?

Tags: opensuse, wine

I am using OpenSUSE, I installed wine on it, and .net 4.0 using wine tricks. I ported windows forms application to linux. My application is used to connect to devices. We use device drivers for it. I got the exception "fixme:thread:NtQueryInformationThread info class 16 not supported yet ?" Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to fix that is to implement ThreadIsIoPending class. Also note that 'fixme' is not an exception, but a diagnostic message, it doesn't mean that something critically bad happened. In your case it's likely it comes directly from .NET runtime or some support library.